# Setting Typescript property to `never` still treats it as required

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type that progressively gets populated at different stages. For example, while creating a `Bar` object, I'd want `Data<DataType.bar>` to contain a completed `Foo` object, but neither `Bar` itself, nor `Baz`, would be part of `Data` yet:

```
enum DataType {
  'foo',
  'bar',
  'baz',
}

type Foo = {
  a: string;
};
type Bar = {
  b: string;
};
type Baz = {
  c: string;
};

type Data<T extends DataType | null = null> = {
  [DataType.foo]: T extends DataType.bar | DataType.baz | null ? Foo : never;
  [DataType.bar]: T extends DataType.baz | null ? Bar : never;
  [DataType.baz]: T extends null ? Baz : never;
};

const myData: Data = {
  [DataType.foo]: { a: 'I should already exist while bar is being created' },
  /*
  [DataType.bar]: {
     b: `I correctly error when uncommented...
         but when commented, DataType.bar also appears to be required?`
  }
  */
};
```

Although `myData` correctly includes an error when `DataType.bar` is included, I also get the following error when it's commented out:

`Type '{ 0: { a: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Data<DataType.bar>': [DataType.bar], [DataType.baz]`

Is there any way to tell typescript that those properties are NOT actually missing based on the `T extends DataType` generic?

**EDIT**: This appears to do what I want, however it seems really repetitive? Is there a better way to do this?

```
type Data<T extends DataType | null = null> = T extends null
  ? {
      [DataType.foo]: Foo;
      [DataType.bar]: Bar;
      [DataType.baz]: Baz;
    }
  : T extends DataType.baz
  ? {
      [DataType.foo]: Foo;
      [DataType.bar]: Bar;
    }
  : T extends DataType.bar
  ? {
      [DataType.foo]: Foo;
    }
  : T extends DataType.foo
  ? {}
  : never;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `interface` and `extends`

```
enum DataType {
  'foo',
  'bar',
  'baz',
}
interface DataFoo { [x:string]: never}
interface DataBar { foo: string; }; 
interface DataBaz extends DataBar { bar: string; };
interface DataAll extends DataBaz { baz: string; };
type Data<T extends DataType | null = null> = T extends null ? DataAll
  : T extends DataType.baz
  ? DataBaz
  : T extends DataType.bar
  ? DataBar
  : T extends DataType.foo
  ? DataFoo
  : never;
const dataFoo: Data<DataType.foo> = {};
const dataBar: Data<DataType.bar> = { foo: "" };
const dataBaz: Data<DataType.baz> = { foo: "", bar: "" };
const dataAll: Data = { foo: "", bar: "", baz:"" };
```

(see [TypeScriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpQDkAZgPamEA0+RARnAE5U2H0BezAvrgJYgLAGxOAGMs8JADFyOKAG0AHgC4AzggZ8A5gF0lUEMABug7nwFDR4xHABCjWWVJ61GkJoDcUTp979BwsVhrOzYoYAUBEAATFSCkOwZZegZndS1Pb19zAKskAEEAGwKwiNAYuNs4UOwodlTXDy93XAQMXLgAHmQSyPKJFDaoAB99MCKoAF5RooA+Sahu8N7Y8HGAfgrCgpo9RdLo2P60TAA6dhoN-pCdhZ6yw+tj4DPGC4qEm73liqeTxzf+tJSDcDMYGM0RKQQGooFFrEC9P0Okc2n9yHMpthMpDoQhYcFGIjrMjHqjkhiHOQ9AAialNXA4mFw+JVIlIElIX7sCk1Rw06mUWqEqC0+mMvHMuBbNlwea8qkigVClKKwV1UWZIA))

Using `type` and the type operator `&`

```
enum DataType {
  'foo',
  'bar',
  'baz',
}
type DataFoo = Record<string,never>;
type DataBar = {foo:string};
type DataBaz = DataBar & {bar:string};
type DataAll = DataBaz & {baz:string};
type Data<T extends DataType | null = null> = T extends null ? DataAll
  : T extends DataType.baz
  ? DataBaz
  : T extends DataType.bar
  ? DataBar
  : T extends DataType.foo
  ? DataFoo
  : never;
const dataFoo: Data<DataType.foo> = {};
const dataBar: Data<DataType.bar> = { foo: "" };
const dataBaz: Data<DataType.baz> = { foo: "", bar: "" };
const dataAll: Data = { foo: "", bar: "", baz:"" };
```

(see [TypeScriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpQDkAZgPamEA0+RARnAE5U2H0BezAvrghlvEgBi5KAF4oAJWABjUgwAmAHgDOCBgEsQAc0ohgAN2AMAfAG4efWIjgAhRmJxlSALlUbtnc70xWkdtg4CtvYAZDj0DK5qmlqeFj5BAIIANsmB1v5QYdjsUe6xXpZBishQwAAeCKDyyr4olgA+UOCpDi3Jxg6lFVUgNc1grQD8dSnJNM5Q3ZXVtUFomAB07DQjQf4TU2UzfXPWC8DLjKt1dgyb073983yLTidBwqSbeoYM5rIgqlDy1k+TxRuSycnXE2Din2+vz8jAB1kUQMOEVBOCgTkmACIMVAIaQvggfhk4Gw4UgEftbuwUdg0eRMRjKFAIvScR88VDrGNSXAHDT0VAsYzmQKGUzic4sayaAQgA))

`Record` is a typescript utility function. `Record<string,never>` is the same as `{[x:string]:never}`

The main benefit is that the length of text increases as `O(Nlevels)`.  In your original it increases as `O(Nlevels^2)`.